# How to link OpenSSL 3.x with Qt in Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, dynamic-linking, qt6

Qt 6.2 (and 6.5) both link to "Windows secure channel" by default. For us this version is not workable as it fails a few socket connections, which otherwise used to work with 1.1.1t etc.

Have downloaded the latest OpenSSL-3.x source code and even their dlls. How to link them with Qt so that `QSslSocket::sslLibraryVersionString()` shows 3.0?

Comment: I am fairly certain that is a compile-time flag and you need to recompile Qt yourself.

Comment: @Botje With some trial and error I observed that, I managed to get "1.1.1t" instead of "secure channel". But after a system restart, I lost that change. Unable to recall how did I manage to get that. If it's not dynamically linkable then it will be a very long process :-(

Comment: Ah, Qt 6.1 has a [`QSslSocket::setActiveBackend`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsslsocket.html#setActiveBackend) method you could call. In that case you could check if OpenSSL is listed in `QSslSocket::availableBackends()`.

Comment: Qt needs to be built with openssl3 headers (it probably already is built that way if you use official binaries) and then you just need to have openssl3 dlls near Qt binaries.